# Cannot See a Web Map on ArcGIS Collector

Tags: arcgis-collector

I have created a web map and it appears that all settings and permissions should allow me to see it.  While I have other maps which I can see in Collector, when I open collector and sign in to this organization account I cannot see it.  The settings seem to be the same as other maps which I can see.

Here are the settings for the feature layer that I am trying to collect data for:

[image]

Any other suggestions to consider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created a few web maps for Collector for ArcGIS and I always do it the same way.

1. I always start off by creating a file geodatabase through ArcMap. (Catalog and Pro will work the same) I make sure to finish all of my symbology, domains, and subtypes before publishing it as a web layer.
2. Go to File-> Sign In...-> Sign in with your ESRI account.
3. Go to File-> Share AS-> Service...-> Publish a Service-> 
   Choose a connection: My Hosted Services('Your organization') Service Name: 
   'Title'.
   I change my capabilities to Feature Access, not Tiled Mapping. Set up your 
   feature access operations to preferences.
   I normally share it with Everyone
4. Then you will want to publish this service.
5. Create it as a web map online and it works without having to even touch the settings.

A suggestion that I would consider is trying to share it with a group that you are a member of.

Comment: I ran through the steps again in ArcGIS Pro.  This time I made sure to change the configuration of the web map to "Editable" (The default is set to "Exploratory").  The new map appears.

Comment: I'm glad it worked out for you! I would have to say this is the most efficient way of conducting operational web maps for Arc Collector. If this isn't how you were doing it before I suggest using these steps from now on.